# test if strings from two datasets match using subject id columns from twi datasets by subject id

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to do a simple matching of two columns, but I need it to match by subject id and the output should be the subject id's which do not match in the two datasets.

data:

```
df1 <- structure (list(
subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945"), 
edta_code = c("EDTA45", "EDTA79", "EDTA20", "EDTA66", "EDTA12", "EDTA74"), 
ipv = c("0", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

```
df2 <- structure (list(
subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", 
"191-1245", "191-1947"), 
edta_code_df2 = c("EDTA45", "EDTA78", "EDTA20", "EDTA66", "EDTA14", "EDTA74")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

what I have tried

```
df3 <- df1 %>% select(subject_id, edta_code)

df3 <- full_join(df3, df2, by = "subject_id")
df$all_matching <- df3$edta_code == df3$edta_code_df2
```

The above code doesn't work, it gives error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, all_matching, value = c(TRUE, FALSE,  : 
  replacement has 7 rows, data has 5
```

desired output:

[image]

where 0 is no and 1 is yes.
Then after that I pull the subject id's with 0.

| subject_id |
| --- |
| 191-6784 |
| 191-1245 |
| 191-1947 |
| 191-1945 |

Note: although the last two subject_ids have the correct codes the subject_ids are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `full_join`, you will need to deal with missing in either `edta_code` or `edta_code_df2` columns. When checking for equality with `==` you can add `!is.na()` so that if either or both of those two columns is missing you will get `FALSE` or 0 for the `matching` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "subject_id") %>%
  select(-ipv) %>%
  mutate(matching = +(edta_code == edta_code_df2 & !is.na(edta_code) & !is.na(edta_code_df2)))

df3

  subject_id edta_code edta_code_df2 matching
1   191-5467    EDTA45        EDTA45        1
2   191-6784    EDTA79        EDTA78        0
3   191-3457    EDTA20        EDTA20        1
4   191-0987    EDTA66        EDTA66        1
5   191-1245    EDTA12        EDTA14        0
6   191-1945    EDTA74          <NA>        0
7   191-1947      <NA>        EDTA74        0

df3 %>%
  filter(matching == 0) %>%
  pull(subject_id)

[1] "191-6784" "191-1245" "191-1945" "191-1947"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  select(-ipv) %>% 
  full_join(df2) %>%  
  mutate(matching = if_else(edta_code == edta_code_df2, 1, 0)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(matching = 0))

Joining with `by = join_by(subject_id)`
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  subject_id edta_code edta_code_df2 matching
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>            <dbl>
1 191-5467   EDTA45    EDTA45               1
2 191-6784   EDTA79    EDTA78               0
3 191-3457   EDTA20    EDTA20               1
4 191-0987   EDTA66    EDTA66               1
5 191-1245   EDTA12    EDTA14               0
6 191-1945   EDTA74    NA                   0
7 191-1947   NA        EDTA74               0
```

Pull the IDs

```
df1 %>% 
  select(-ipv) %>% 
  full_join(df2) %>%  
  mutate(matching = if_else(edta_code == edta_code_df2, 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(!matching %in% c(1))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  subject_id edta_code edta_code_df2 matching
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>            <dbl>
1 191-6784   EDTA79    EDTA78               0
2 191-1245   EDTA12    EDTA14               0
3 191-1945   EDTA74    NA                  NA
4 191-1947   NA        EDTA74              NA
```